# ajax get xmlHttpRequest load time

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, load-time

Is there a way to get an xmlHttpRequest load time?

Otherwise I'll have to set a function that count it, so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there isn't an execution time included as part of the XMLHTTPRequest object. You can, however, use JS to calculate this value:

```js
const start = Date.now();

// Execute request

alert( "Request took: " + ( Date.now() - start ) );
```

For more info on the data that *is* stored in the XMLHTTPRequest object, see [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).